# Is reposting a closed question considered to be spam?

Tags: discussion, closed-questions, re-open, spam

A new user recently posted the following question:

[What does the Rebbe mean by "{the sixth Rebbe} will redeem us", in his first discourse?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/139402/what-does-the-rebbe-mean-by-the-sixth-rebbe-will-redeem-us-in-his-first-dis)

Some community members associated the post with another question and voted to close it as a duplicate. The user appears to have edited and submitted for review in order to have the question re-opened to no avail.

The user then reposted his question with negligible modification (i.e. using substantially the same language and sources):

[What do I make of these sources the seem to indicate the Rebbe saying the sixth Rebbe is moshiach?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/140062/what-do-i-make-of-these-sources-the-seem-to-indicate-the-rebbe-saying-the-sixth)

While the user's apparent frustration is understandable, what is (or ought be) the policy regarding such reposted questions and those who engage in such behavior? It seems to border on spam-like activity intended to evade being subject to community regulation. Thoughts?

Comment: You can close vote the new question as a duplicate of the other one. Do **not** cast spam flags as that will also inflict a -100 penalty for the user when these flags go through. If the re-posting continues, raise a custom mod-flag with links to the reposted question(s). Moderators will handle it from there.